# How to remove all elements from Array object except given id using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to remove all elements from `projectSet` except when `id = myid`.
I came across `splice()` but not sure how to make it work in my code.
For example:

```
var myid = 2
var projectSet =
[
{id: 1, name: "P1", description: "D1"},
{id: 2, name: "P2", description: "D2"},
{id: 3, name: "P3", description: "D3"},
]

for(var i = 0; i < projectSet.length; i++){
   if (projectSet[i].id = myid)
      {
         if (i > -1)
          {
            this.projectSet.splice(i,1); // This is not working as expected.
          }
       }
}
console.log(projectSet)
```

Expected output:

```
var projectSet =
    [
    {id: 2, name: "P2", description: "D2"}
    ]
```

Comment: are you looking for a real mutation of the (original) array reference like demonstrated with the provided example code or does/did generating a new array by e.g. `filter` already solve the problem entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to

- Use `===` instead of `=` (`=` is the assignment operator)
- Don't `splice` while iterating over an array, else you'll skip the next index (eg, after splicing an item at index 1, what used to be at index 2 will immediately slide down to index 1, but you'll proceed to compare index 2 on the next iteration, skipping what used to be at index 2 and is now at index 1)

Use `filter` instead.

```js
var myid = 2
var projectSet =
    [
        { id: 1, name: "P1", description: "D1" },
        { id: 2, name: "P2", description: "D2" },
        { id: 3, name: "P3", description: "D3" },
    ]

const filtered = projectSet.filter(obj => obj.id === myid);
console.log(filtered)
```